# Akka HTTP Update Logic

Tags: scala, rest, akka

I'm just beginning to learn scala/akka and was confused by the following code used to update a question. I'm working through this following tutorial:http://danielasfregola.com/2016/02/07/how-to-build-a-rest-api-with-akka-http/

The part that confuses me is why when handling a PUT request to update a question does it do the following:

```
      val updatedQuestion = updateEntity(question)
      deleteQuestion(id).flatMap { _ =>
        createQuestion(updatedQuestion).map(_ => Some(updatedQuestion))
```

From what I can understand, deleteQuestion already excluded the question we are trying to update (with a filterNot), but then why does it do a flatMap and then yet another map on top of createQuestion. Many thanks!

File here: 
https://github.com/DanielaSfregola/quiz-management-service/blob/master/tutorial-5/src/main/scala/com/danielasfregola/quiz/management/services/QuestionService.scala

Comment: This logic is first removing the old question from the `Vector` and then re-adding it back via the call to create.  The case class itself is immutable, so you cannot do an in place edit, so instead you have to remove and then add back with the changes.

Comment: Thanks cmbaxter. This makes sense, hence why they needed to make a new Question object. But the part that still confuses me is the flatMap against deleteQuestion. What sequence exactly is operating against given it looks to be a Future[Unit] return type ?

Also, why wouldn't "questions = questions :+ question" do the trick, like was done in createQuestions ?

Comment: Flatmap allows you order computations, i.e in this case it guarantees that `createQuestion` would be executed ONLY after `deleteQuestion` completes successfully. Otherwise (without flatMap), these ops would run in parallel => you can't guarantee that delete won't remove just inserted updated question.

Comment: Thanks 4lex1v ! Ah so it's basically a trick to sequence the operations. I guess finally after that, why we have to then call .map back on the createQuestion ?